# How to populate form elements with data for editing in zend 2.2.4

Tags: zend-framework

am new to zend framework 2.2.4 and just trying out some aspects..Am trying to edit data using a form i created using zend form..This code is in the manual but cant get it to work..
                try
         {
         $album=$this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
         }
        catch(\Exception $ex)
         {
        return   $this->redirect()->toRoute('Album',array('action'=>'index'));
                                         }
        $form = new AlbumForm();

```
            $form->bind($album);
```

This is my error message:
          File:C:\xampp\htdocs\trend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Stdlib      \Hydrator\ArraySerializable.php:29
  Message:
         Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable::extract expects the provided object to implement getArrayCopy()

i have really tried to get past this..but i just cant..Please help..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you may not have created "getArrayCopy()" method in src\your module\Model\